# validating typeos in email on c#

Tags: c#, email

We have a lot of emails being manually typed into one of our services. We do the normal email regular expression checks but occasionally one of them is a typeo for example `contactmee@gmail.com` instead of `contactme@gmail.com`. Does anyone know of any more extreme validation lengths we can go to reduce instances of this? Our service runs on windows and has access to the internet.

Comment: How extreme do you want?  Have a safe recipients list, if the recipient isn't on the list somebody other than the sender has to verify it for typos?

Comment: @Smudge202 - thanks for your response. Unfortunately we don't know the email addresses in advance.

Comment: Sticking with the _safe list_ theme, how about if the e-mail isn't on a given list, pop-up a dialogue requiring information about the e-mail being added - make the user re-type the e-mail address as part of the process. Then you can compare the two and hope they didn't copy/paste the typo email twice?  Or are you after some sort of amazing spell checker than can work with concatenated words?  If so, perhaps you could use google (or similar service)?  i.e. Send "contactmee" to the search engine, and see what the suggested corrections are?

Comment: Just checked, this particular example at least google autocorrected to "Contactme": http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=contactmee&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-gb:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&rlz=&redir_esc=&ei=1tI7TvDVOYSohAe_kK2oDw

Comment: And the related api details: http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/610/admin_searchexp/ce_understanding.html#h1impsea

Comment: @Henk - nothing is inherently wrong with it but when we send to addresses that are typed wrong, they bounce which we'd like to prevent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the input mechanism for these emails - a form?

The traditional method of eliminating typos is having 2 fields; **Email** and **Re-enter Email**. Disable copy-pasting into the 2nd field to force them to type it again. That way, the chance of the same typo being made twice is greatly reduced.

Comment: yep it's a form. The reason we don't have two fields is the users have to type their email (often with a queue of other users) through a touch screen (an old style one not an iPad) - which is actually quite hard if they don't do it regularly. We timed many users taking > 30 seconds. The second field would add to this.

Comment: i.e time vs accuracy trade off

Comment: In which case, you'll just need to compare `(extra input time per user * number of users)` vs. `development time it takes to intelligently detect a typo`. I predict many false positives from such a system which may be a false economy even if you can develop such a system rapidly via Google APIs. Perhaps a 'confirm' dialog box forcing them to read what they typed would be a halfway-house?